# Can I use an instant bridge as an improvised weapon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, wild-shape, improvised-weaponry

Assuming 40+ strength with shikigami manipulation, could one use an instant bridge as an improvised weapon? Penalties are fine.

I've built a goliath druid / hinyasi brawler, so I do have a secondary question: Would the bridge grow with you if you were to wild shape into a huge-sized humanoid giant?

I'm a relative novice at Pathfinder, so any help or advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes, if you're large enough

The rules say:

> To determine the size category and appropriate damage for an improvised weapon, compare its relative size and damage potential to the weapon list to find a reasonable match.

Your instant bridge has a length of 30ft and a weight of 300 pounds.

Checking the [size table](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/space-reach-threatened-area-templates/), I see that a Huge (tall) creature has a natural reach of 15ft, which means that a Huge reach weapon would have a reach of 30ft.  So we might compare your bridge to a Huge polearm, such as a Huge bec-de-corbin, which would have a reach of 30ft and a weight of 48 pounds.

(Weapon weight doubles when you go up a size category, which seems wrong -- shouldn't the increase be a factor of eight?  Rules As Written says it doubles, though.)

If your DM cares more about your weapon size than its weight, your bridge can be modeled as a Huge polearm.  (If your DM tries to find an appropriate weapon to model a 300-pound weight, they're going to wind up larger than Colossal.)

### But not in the way you want

But it sounds like your real question here is: "hey, can I use the improvised-weapon rules to get around the normal restrictions on weapon reach?"  The answer is: probably no, because your DM should model your improvised weapon as a weapon with the same reach.

### Weapons do resize

You've also asked about weapon resizing.  A goliath druid shifting into a Huge giant uses the *giantform II* spell, which is a transmutation(polymorph) effect.  The [transmutation rules](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Transmutation) say:

> When you cast a polymorph spell that changes you into a creature of the animal, dragon, elemental, magical beast, plant, or vermin type, all of your gear melds into your body...

> If your new form does not cause your equipment to meld into your form, the equipment resizes to match your new size.

So your weapon would resize.

Answer (score 1):

From [Improvised Weapons](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/#TOC-Improvised-Weapons)

> Sometimes objects not crafted to be weapons nonetheless see use in combat. Because such objects are not designed for this use, any creature that uses an improvised weapon in combat is considered to be nonproficient with it and takes a –4 penalty on attack rolls made with that object. To determine the size category and appropriate damage for an improvised weapon, compare its relative size and damage potential to the weapon list to find a reasonable match. An improvised weapon scores a threat on a natural roll of 20 and deals double damage on a critical hit. An improvised thrown weapon has a range increment of 10 feet.

So to use it's extended form as improvised weapon, you'll need to convince your GM that it's comparable to something from the weapons table. At normal player sizes, that's a bit of a stretch.

It collapsed form, it might count as an improvised club or something similar.

Regardless, the GM will have to make a ruling on this.

The bridge in extended form will not "grow with" anyone. It gives exact measurements for how big it will become, and therefore will always expand to that exact size.

Comment: "The bridge in extended form will not "grow with" anyone. It gives exact measurements for how big it will become, and therefore will always expand to that exact size." This is debatable for improvised weapons but polymorphing into a larger humanoid does not increase weapon size anyway (unless it says so like Enlarge Person or Righteous Might).

Comment: I admit I stopped thinking when I had one rule why it doesn't work, but I admit that's a completely separate reason it works the way it does.